# QuickWatch window intellisense problem

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

I use ReSharper but I cannot use intellisense on the QuickWatch window. Resharper disables this feature. Do you know any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also noticed that my intellisense menu doesn't automatically show up in the QuickWatch window.

After typing at least 1 character in the *Name* field of the QuickWatch window, you can manually make the intellisense menu appear by pressing *Ctrl+Space*.

Comment: As of VS2010, this is called "Edit.CompleteWord" in the keyboard mapping scheme.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in Resharper and not one that's going to be resolved anytime soon, it seems:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-179392?query=fix+for